# why is this code for audio not working in my website?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have tried multiple ways of adding audio to my webpage in a button functions but the audio does not play when the button is clicked. My browser is well updated to the latest version so that's not a problem. This is the code below, it would be really helpful if someone could tell me what's wrong with it.

Js

```
const rollSound = new Audio("sounds/short-guided-meditation.ogg");
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener("click", e => rollSound.play());
```

Html

```
<button class="playsound" id="play" onclick="rollSound.play()" >Play</button>
```

Comment: I removed the node.js tag as this question isn't related to node but browser-run javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting multiple click events. They could be overriding eachother. `rollSound` could be `undefined` in the html. Generally these things should show errors in the console.

```
const rollSound = new Audio("sounds/short-guided-meditation.ogg");
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener("click", e => rollSound.play());
```

Remove your on click handler from the html

```
<button class="playsound" id="play">Play</button>
```

Comment: hi, thankyou so much for your help, I dont know why but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console of your browser? Could you do a`console.log(rollSound)` ? Maybe there is something wrong with your `audio` object. And are you coding in your local file system?

Comment: Hi dear, I found the problem. your code worked perfectly fine for me. Thankyou so much for your time and effort. The problem was that the html page was linked to the wrong js file.

Comment: Nice! Can you accept the answer? By doing this you would 'close' your question. Have a nice day!